# Persian PDF file to Word file Converter

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, farsi, document-conversion

**Persian PDF to Word Converter.**

I have created an application to convert the PDF file into a word file. There is a problem with Persian PDf files when I try to convert them. The application converts the pdf into a word file but the text format is not readable, It will try to put the Letters and vice versa.

Here is the code which I have written.

```py
import os.path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from pdf2docx import Converter


def open_file():
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename()
    file_path = os.path.basename(file_name).split('/')[-1]
    change_file_type = file_path.replace('.pdf', '.docx')

    pdf_file = file_name
    docx_file = change_file_type

    cv = Converter(pdf_file)
    cv.convert(docx_file)
    cv.close()


root = Tk()
root.title('PDF2Word Converter')

label_title = ttk.Label(root, text='Welcome to PDF Converter!')
label_open_pdf = ttk.Label(root, text='Open PDF: ')
label_Developer = ttk.Label(root, text='Developer: Behrooz Sharify')

open_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Open', command=open_file)

label_title.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
label_open_pdf.grid(row=2, column=0)
label_Developer.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
open_button.grid(row=2, column=3)

root.geometry('296x70')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

You can refer to the picture I uploaded here for the output problem:

[image: text is not readable]

Answer (score -1):

I have used pdf2docx as well and it's far from perfection, I would recommend some online converters like smallpdf.com and pdfocr.org etc, the latter lets you convert scanned pdf to word for free.